# Is there a way to transpose a dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a data like so

```r
A B C D Type
1 1 2 3 Le
2 4 6 3 Me
1 4 6 4 Ne
3 4 4 9 Ke
```

And I want to make so

```r
Val Le Me Ne Ke
A   1  2  1  3
B   1  4  4  4
C   2  6  6  4
D   3  3  4  9
```

How can I convert this type of data using R? Is there function for this?

Comment: thank you. How to make this type of edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table::transpose`

```
data.table::transpose(df, make.names = 'Type',keep.names = 'Val')
```

-output

```
  Val Le Me Ne Ke
1   A  1  2  1  3
2   B  1  4  4  4
3   C  2  6  6  4
4   D  3  3  4  9
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L), B = c(1L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
    C = c(2L, 6L, 6L, 4L), D = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 9L), Type = c("Le", 
    "Me", "Ne", "Ke")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are starting from a data frame:

```r
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
A B C D Type
1 1 2 3 Le
2 4 6 3 Me
1 4 6 4 Ne
3 4 4 9 Ke
")
```

```r
## transpose numeric columns
x1 <- t(dd[,1:4])
## prepend value column and convert to data frame
x2 <- data.frame(Val = rownames(x1), x1)
## set other column names
names(x2)[2:5] <- dd$Type
## clean up redundant row names
rownames(x2) <- NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Using 'reshape2' R package, you can first melt the data into long format and reshape from long to wide format with one column for each unique value:

```
library(reshape2)

# Create your data
df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 1, 3),
             B = c(1, 4, 4, 4),
             C = c(2, 6, 6, 4),
             D = c(3, 3, 4, 9),
             Type = factor(c("Le", "Me", "Ne", "Ke"),levels = c("Le", "Me", "Ne", "Ke")))


# Melt your dat into long format
dfmelt <- melt(df, id.vars = "Type", variable.name = "Val")

# reshape the data  into wide format, with unique column for each value in 'Type
dfwide <- dcast(dfmelt, Val ~ Type, value.var = "value")

# Print the resulting data frame
dfwide

  Val Le Me Ne Ke
1   A  1  2  1  3
2   B  1  4  4  4
3   C  2  6  6  4
4   D  3  3  4  9
```